# Dict order in python

Tags: python, dictionary, nltk

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Python dictionary, keep keys/values in same order as declared](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1867861/python-dictionary-keep-keys-values-in-same-order-as-declared)

Good day to all.
I'm working on a sentiment analysis application in python (to which I am new) and I am experiencing a problem.
I'm using the bag of words feature extractor but I'm experiencing one major problem when the bag of words function is called.
Let's assume that we have the following text: "He will be the winner."
When I call my function which has the following code: `dict([(word, True) for word in words])` I get the following result:

> {'will': True, 'be': True, 'the': True, 'winner': True, 'He': True}

Which is OK except for the fact that the word ordering is off.
If I use a loop like that one:

```
for i in range(0, len(words)):
```

The order of the output is OK but I don't know how I can create a dictionary out of that.
So can anyone suggest a way to get my bag of words without messing up the ordering of the words?

Thank you for your time and help.

Teo